# Using OR condition in OPA rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I want to use an OR operation to combine the following conditions:

- the count of my `arr` is not equal to `0`
- my `email` does not contain `"test.com"`

Currently I am using the built-in function `any()`:

```
any([count(arr) != 0, not contains(email, "test.com")])
```

However my rule is producing an error.

How can I achieve and improve this in one line?

Comment: See also the related [issue #3239](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/issues/3239) which suggests alternatives to `any()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `not` keyword is a bit of a special case in that it can't be used inside of many contexts such as the array of your example. I believe this could be improved in OPA, but until then you can trivially avoid it for at most cases, like the one you provided:

```
any([count(arr) != 0, contains(email, "test.com") == false])
```

Answer (score 9):

More generally, Rego does not allow OR-ing statements in the same function. Using `any()` works well for simple cases, but can become unwieldy for complex ones so it is considered an antipattern.

Instead, Rego uses [incremental rules](https://www.eknert.com/tech/2020/02/04/incremental-rules-in-opa.html), where every statement *within each Rule* is AND-ed together, and rules of the same name are OR-ed together.

Consider the following `deny` rule. In short, it says that we will deny the request if at least one of:

1. The user is not an admin, or
2. Today is Sunday.

```
deny {
    input.role != "admin"
}

deny {
    time.weekday(time.now_ns()) == "Sunday"
}
```

This would only allow requests to the `admin` role on days other than Sunday. If instead we said:

```
deny {
    input.role != "admin"
    time.weekday(time.now_ns()) == "Sunday"
}
```

We would then only deny requests from non-`admin` roles on Sunday. Requests from `admin` would always be allowed.

Comment: That’s a useful addition!